# Firebase Dynamic link get broken after first time install from Play Store and does not open deep Link after first install

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a `Dynamic Link` in Firebase Console. I have Refer option in Application, which creates a Dynamic Link and the link is share through some media. As per Firebase documentation, if app is not installed already it opens Play Store and enable user to download the app. But once the app is downloaded, (as per documentation) it should show `Continue` option to open the app for first time so that expected Dynamic link flow will work. But I have not received such a option for First install from Play Store and it shows `Open` option which breaks the Dynamic Link and opens the app from start.
The code for generating `Dynamic Link` is

```
String e="https://myappinvite.page.link/?link=https://myappinvite.page.link/?referid=10&apn=com.learnandro&amv=16&st=Please Install the App&si="+some Image Url+"&afl=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app Package name";

Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                        .createDynamicLink()
                        .setLongLink(Uri.parse(e))
                        .buildShortDynamicLink()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                                Uri get=task.getResult().getShortLink();
                                Intent sh=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                sh.setType("text/plain");
                                sh.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Vi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ew the Amazing Event   "+get);
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sh,"View"));
                            }
                        });
```

The `Manifest` file looks like this

```
<activity android:name=".login.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <data
                    android:host="myappinvite.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is code for Receiving Dynamic Link if found inside `onCreate` of Activity

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData !=null) {
                            Uri getDynamicLink=pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                            String id=getDynamicLink.getQueryParameter("referid");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

What actually is missing for not getting the whole experience of Dynamic Link ?

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: This feature is not supported in Firebase Dynamic link. Try for some another solution